# formula for difference between start & end time includes milliseconds in Excel

Tags: excel, ods

I want to find the time difference between start & end time using Excel

my Data :

```
A1 = 16:00:03:38
B2 = 16:14:13:58
```

which is in pattern of  "h:mm:ss:ms"   h=hours,mm=minutes,ss=seconds,ms=milliseconds.

am using like this =B2-A1    but it not  giving result  instead of it giving output like this " #VALUE! "

if i change like this

```
A1 = 16:00:03.38
B2 = 16:14:13.58
```

answer is = 00:14:10:20
the answer  is giving perfect

but i don't want to change  :  to  .
is it possible to take difference  between two time's  as per my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Let the formula do the conversion:

```
=TIMEVALUE(LEFT(B2,8) & "." & RIGHT(B2,2))-TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A1,8) & "." & RIGHT(A1,2))
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Any special settings that need to be activated Gary? Like 1904?

Comment: @rohrl77  The formula will only fail if there are **any leading or trailing blanks** in the cells.............please verify that the data is **11** characters in length.............1904 should not be needed.

Comment: `LEN()` returned 11 characters for both

Comment: @rohrl77  Is the problem my format of **.20** rather than **:20** for the milliseconds ??

Comment: I just tried to do the simple subtraction that Togara mentioned should work, and it doesn't work for me either. Does that give you a result on your Excel version?

Comment: My Excel installation has european settings such as ";" instead of ","... perhaps there are also time formats that are different in the background which Excel doesn't recognize under EU settings which it does under US/standard ones

Comment: @Gary'sStudent turns out the syntax, basically  the separator is differnt in OpenOffice. `;` instead of `,`.